# Creating a wrapper function that uses tidyverse-like syntax

Tags: r, wrapper

I'm trying to create a wrapper function that will let me use tidyverse-like syntax (i.e. replacing `dat$col` with `dat, col`) whilst simultaneously adding some default arguments. I'm struggling with the first part - likely because I don't have a good grasp of base R (and maybe data masking?)

```r
# What I would like to recreate
summary(mtcars$mpg)
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#>   10.40   15.43   19.20   20.09   22.80   33.90

# My attempt
tidy_summary <- function(data, variable) {
        variable_name <- {{  variable  }}
        summary(data$variable_name)
}

tidy_summary(mtcars, mpg)
#> Error in tidy_summary(mtcars, mpg): object 'mpg' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I tried using the `[` operator instead, or passing the arguments as strings, without luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```r
tidy_summary <- function(data, variable) {
  
  summary(data[[deparse(substitute(variable))]])
}

tidy_summary(mtcars, mpg)
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#>   10.40   15.43   19.20   20.09   22.80   33.90
```

The `$` operator doesn't work here because this is always interpreted as-is. That is, `data$variable_name` will always look for a column literally called `variable_name`. It will not be substituted for the name stored in the variable `variable_name`. Instead, we use the `[[` operator and pass a string containing the actual column name, which we can get by `deparse(substitute(variable))`

<sup>Created on 2022-09-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Allan´s answer is the way to go. Just for complement, there was [discussion](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1514) on creating a better(?) `summary()` function, one that could take colunms as arguments. One could use `skimr::skim()` the same way you were trying with `summary()`:

```
tidy_summary <- function(data, variable) {
        variable_name <- {{variable}}
        skimr::skim(mtcars, variable_name)
}

tidy_summary(mtcars, "mpg")
```

Or if you want to be able to avoid passing the columns as strings, `ensym()` will do the trick:

```
tidy_summary <- function(data, variable) {
        variable_name <- ensym(variable)
        skimr::skim(mtcars, variable_name)
}

tidy_summary(mtcars, mpg)
```

More on quasiquotation on [Advanced R Chapter 19](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html).

Comment: Thanks. I used `summary()` just as an example - my real use case was with `summarytools::descr()`. That's an interesting thread though - I do think that `dplyr` is lacking in this respect.